# How to generate random integers 0 to 0x7FFFFFFF?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10

This doesn't work:

```
for (int p = 0; p < 10; p++) {
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd);
    uniform_real_distribution<int> dis(0, INT_MAX);
    printf("%i\n", dis(gen));
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: _it doesn't work_ could you please clarify? It doesn't compile, or it runs but doesn't do what you want? What are you expecting from 10 integers?

Comment: Don't reseed the generator in the loop. Generate in the loop, move everything else outside the loop. And make sure `INT_MAX` is 0x7FFFFFFF or you're possibly in for another fun surprise.

Comment: Also, for integers `uniform_real_distribution` isn't the best choice. `uniform_int_distribution` is a better choice.

Comment: Oh and watch out. Some ports of GCC have hilariously bad `random_device` implementations.

Comment: @user4581301  Yup.  Under close scrutiny, even the venerable MT [isn't that great](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/50059/why-is-the-mersenne-twister-regarded-as-good).

Answer (score 4):

You have few mistakes in your code.

1. You should move creation of `random_device` and seeding `mt19937` outside the for loop. I'll also suggest the same for `uniform_real_distribution<int>`
2. `mt19937` takes in the constructor value of seed not `random_device` so you have to call it to get seed(`rd()`)
3. You should use `uniform_int_distribution<int>` if you are generating integers
4. If your intention is to generate number to 0x7FFFFFFF you should put this number explicitly but if you want to get numbers to max `int` value i'll suggest using more C++ style `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`

Here is working example:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <random>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  random_device rd;
  mt19937 gen(rd());
  uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(0, std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
  for (int p = 0; p < 10; p++) {
    printf("%i\n", dis(gen));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help very much.